# python flask - Post request to a route which needs login

Tags: python, flask

How can I make a post request to a endpoint which needs to be logged in?

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/post')
    return (res.text, res.status_code, res.headers.items())

@app.route('/post',methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def handle_post():
    return("hello world")
```

The login_required is similar to this:

```
def login_required(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def secure_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if "SESSION_ID_KEY" not in session:
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return secure_function
```

Right now '/' redirects me to the login page. I understand the `request.post` generates a new post request outside of this app's context hence `login_required` fails eventhough I am logged in. How can I implement this properly?

Comment: I wouldnt program your API to call itself. Instead of /post being a route, you could make it a normal function and have the / route execute that function instead of making an entirely new request out of it. That would just be res = handle_post()

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 yeah makes sense! But what I am actually trying to do is when a user submits a form (POST) login is required and after login i am trying to redirect to the '/post' route.